# Sendgrid Web API set multiple users in reply_to field with C#

Tags: c#, api, sendgrid

I´m using Sendgrid Email Service with the Library for C# and trying to set multiple users in the ReplyTo field.

This is my code that sends the E-Mail

```
var msg = new SendGridMessage()
{
    Subject = SomeSubject,
    From = new MailAddress("from@mail.com", "From name"),
    To = new MailAddress[] {new MailAddress("destination@mail.com","destinationName")},
    Bcc = new MailAddress[]
    {
        new MailAddress("BccDestination@mail.com", "BccDestinationName"),
    },
    ReplyTo = new MailAddress[]{
        new MailAddress("someone@email.com", "Jhon Doe"),
        new MailAddress("jsmith@email.com", "Jhon Smith"),
    },

    Html = SomeHtml
};
```

When i check for the Email sended, and i try to answer it, only appears the first Mail Address (someone@email.com) that i added and there is no trace of the second one (jsmith@email.com). What can i do?

Comment: You cannot do this. The [SMTP specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822#section-4) does not permit multiple reply-to addresses,and consequently the sendgrid API doesn't support it.

Comment: I understand...i wonder why the ReplyTo is defined as an Array, that have no sense :/

Comment: The Sendgrid API is quite weird. I have no idea why it expects an array. However I don't think any mail client will support multiple Reply-To addresses even if you could send them. The specification doesn't allow it.

Comment: @solarissmoke why would you say that?